# Handling multiple HTTP GET requests on same TCP connection parallely

Tags: php, json, http

I am very new to learning PHP. I am trying to create a PHP script that would handle multiple GET request which are JSON encoded coming from a clients software on a single TCP connection to the PHP script simultaneously.

Whilst reading through I encountered the "HTTP pipe-lining, processing requests in parallel" article on StackOverflow. Well I would want to process the requests as and when they arrive. By design the requests are pipe-lined, hence the requests are processed one by one.

The problem here being if the client software makes 100 requests to the PHP script with a difference of a few milliseconds, my PHP script would take some time to process each request and eventually add on immense amount of time before the last request is processed and sent back to the requesting entity.

I am using $_GET method for retrieving the requests. I have looked for this information and don't seem to find anything substantial. I would appreciate any help on this. Could anyone kindly guide me in the right direction.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a web server, like Apache, this is handled for you, in the exact manner you are describing.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response. I am using Apache web server. Is there any specific setting on the web server that I need to make so that my PHP script can process these requests simultaneously. Im currently reading about persistent connections in HTTP but cant seem to find a way to get this to work. Thanks again.

Comment: No, you just need to make sure your PHP doesn't have any bottlenecks, like multiple `UPDATE` calls to the same tables, which will cause blocking by the first SQL

Comment: Thank you. The PHP script does not deal with any database. I intend to parse individual requests parallely coming from a same requesting entity over a single TCP connection. Currently the requests are flowing in one by one using a $_GET session in my PHP script. The script processes requests serially and puts the output in a JSON encoded array for responding back to the requesting entity. Once the final request is processed, the script then sends back the entire response to the requesting entity. This is causing the script to process until last request before responding. Parallel process reqd.